# Test the equality of two generalized Lorenz curves

Tags: r, dataframe, simulation, hypothesis-test

I am trying to test two generalized Lorenz curves using the `rtip`package. Please see the code below.

```
library(rtip)
X = data.frame(ipuc = rchisq(20, 5))
Y = data.frame(ipuc = rchisq(20, 5))

testGL(X, Y, ipuc = "ipuc", hhcsw = NULL,
       hhsize = NULL, generalized = TRUE, alpha = 0.05)
```

But I got the error message saying `Error in dataset1[, hhcsw] : incorrect number of dimensions.`

The following code is from the `rtip` user manual. This is working fine.

```
library(rtip)
data(eusilc2)
ATdataset1 <- setupDataset(eusilc2, country = "AT", region = "Burgenland")
ATdataset2 <- setupDataset(eusilc2, country = "AT", region = "Carinthia")
testGL(ATdataset1, ATdataset2, generalized = TRUE, samplesize = 10, alpha = 0.05)
```

I am unsure how to resolve this issue and properly structure the data frame for the simulated data. I would greatly appreciate any advice you could provide.

Comment: Try `testGL(cbind(X, DB090=1, HX040=1), cbind(Y, DB090=1, HX040=1), generalized=TRUE)`.